# How to get code coverage percentage for latest build from TFS 2017u2 using PowerShell & REST API

Tags: rest, api, powershell, tfs

Using PowerShell, how can I query Team Foundation Server 2017 Update 2 (on-premises) to get the code coverage percentage metric from the latest completed gated check-in?

I've not found a clear API call to use in the MS reference documentation. In the web interface, I can see in the dashboard for a given completed build the percentage value and a link to download the entire Visual Studio coverage file. I don't want the file, though. I just want to make an API call and get the percent coverage value for the last successful build of a given definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the docs for VSTS's REST API are down right now, but this should get you started ([pulled from Google's Cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:f5lPzldIyqMJ:https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/code-coverage%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)).

This endpoint handles everything related to Tests and Code Coverage.

```
https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/codeCoverage?api-version={version}[&buildId={int}&flags={int}]
```

Provide values for the following and then run this `Invoke-RestMethod` to get the data back.

```
$Instance = 'fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com' #your URL here
$ProjectName = #YourProjectNameHere
$buildID = #YourBuildIDHere
$version = '2.0-preview'

Invoke-RestMethod -uri https://$Instance/DefaultCollection/$ProjectName/_apis/test/codeCoverage?api-version=$version
```

Here's a sample response you can get back:

```
Status code: 200
{
  "value": [
    {
      "configuration": {
        "id": 51,
        "flavor": "Debug",
        "platform": "Any CPU",
        "uri": "vstfs:///Build/Build/363",
        "project": {}
      },
      "state": "0",
      "lastError": "",
      "modules": [
        {
          "blockCount": 2,
          "blockData": "Aw==",
          "name": "fabrikamunittests.dll",
          "signature": "c27c5315-b4ec-3748-9751-2a20280c37d5",
          "signatureAge": 1,
          "statistics": {
            "blocksCovered": 2,
            "linesCovered": 4
          },
          "functions": []
        }
      ],
      "codeCoverageFileUrl": "..."
    }
  ],
  "count": 1
}
```

It looks like blocksCovered and livesCovered are probably the closest you'll get from the API. Let me know if you need some help or get stuck. Eventually, the [docs will be back online at this URL](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/code-coverage).

Comment: Wow @FoxDeploy - that was a quick, accurate response. Thanks so much! I'll take you up on that offer of help if I get stuck.